# The value can be obtained in the constructor function, but TypeError: Cannot read property'xxx' of undefined is output in the render function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native

In `console.log (data ["users"] ["userId"] ["points"])` in `getData ()` of the code below, 20 is output.

But in `render ()`
`<Text> {JSON.stringify (this.state.users.userId.points)} </ Text>`
When you run

> TypeError: Cannot read property'points' of undefined
> Error is output.

How do I  {JSON.stringify (this.state.users.userId.points)} </ Text>
Can it be output as 20?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import { FloatingAction } from "react-native-floating-action";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import env from '../../env.json';

interface Props {
  navigation: any;
  route:any;
  authorId:string;
  postId:string;
  userId:string;
  win:string;
  wni:string;
  ideas:any;
  }

  interface State {
    actions:{
      text:string,
      icon:JSX.Element,
      name:string,
      position:number
    }[],
    data:any,
    points:number
    users:any
  }

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: env.apiKey,
    authDomain: env.authDomain,
    databaseURL: env.databaseURL,
    projectId: env.projectId,
    storageBucket: env.storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: env.messagingSenderId,
    appId: env.appId,
    measurementId: env.measurementId
  };

  if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

  const db = firebase.firestore();

  export class Rank extends React.Component<Props,State> {
      constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.state = {

            actions:[
              {
                text: "Write down features",
                icon: <Icon name="list" size={20}/>,
                name: "feature",
                position: 2
              },
              {
                text: "Post your idea",
                icon: <Icon name="lightbulb" size={20}/>,
                name: "idea",
                position: 1

              }
            ],
            data:{},
            points:0,
            users:{}
          }

          this.getData()
      }

      async getData(){
        let firestoreData = await db.collection("posts").doc(this.props.route.params.postId).get()
        let data = firestoreData.data()

        this.setState({
          data:data,
          users:data["users"]

        })

        console.log(data["users"]["userId"]["points"])
      }

      render(){
        return (
            <View
            style={styles.backgroundImage}
            >
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.users.userId.points)}</Text>
            </View>
        )
      }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundImage: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
      },
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your error this.state.users.userId is undefined so the code fails when you try to fetch points of undefined. Try destructuring the objects one by one and see what happens step by step, I think you are getting this error in the first render where there is nothing in the state so it fails with this error. Try the below code and see what happens.

```
render(){
    const { userId } = this.state.users;
    return (
        <View
        style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <Text>{userId ? JSON.stringify(userId.points): "Loading data.."}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```